# Does column size increase break SELECT *?

Tags: mysql

I searched a little bit on this topic before realizing it is somewhat tricky (for me, at least) to come up with an effective search phrase for it because it overlaps with other common topics.

So here is my question spelled out:

Suppose I have a varchar column that is going to be altered (increased in size).

And I also know that there is code (I know this is bad practice! but that code is what it is at this stage - lobbying developers to change it is a later step) that uses SELECT *.

Will the altered column break queries that use SELECT *, or will that code continue to function?

Thanks in advance for any help.

jrdevdba

Comment: Does MySQL have a maximum size for `varchar` strings? If so, you could have trouble if in a query string concatenation makes a new string that is longer than the maximum. This is a problem in Oracle, for example, where `varchar`s historically were a maximum of 4000 characters long.

Answer (score 1):

"Maximum row size for mysql" is the terminology you are probably looking to search for - that finds a useful stack overflow page at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349361/mysql-how-to-workaround-the-row-size-limit-of-66-kbytes

That suggests a maximum row size (excluding blob types which are stored off-page) of 64Kb, and has a couple of useful looking links with more detail.